# Number of Work items not matching get_global_size openCL

Tags: opencl

I've a strange situation for openCL application
Global_work_size = 1920x1080,Local_work_size = 512,Work_Dim = 1.
In my kernel, I'm able to see correct values for 
get_global_size(2073600) and get_num_groups(4050).
However, get_global_id shows only 518399 which is 1/4 times of actual value.
Similary, get_group_id is showing 1012 which is 1/4 times of actual value.
Because of this, work_item used for indexing is incomplete.
Suggestions to solve this.

Comment: It cannot be. Check the dimensions, and that you are not passing wrong values, or that you are not reading properly the results from  get_global_id and  get_group_id

Comment: I did further checks on my experiment. I've two args to kernel ,char * in and char * out. Here there is no problem when I attemp; out[global_id(0)] = in[global_id(0)];. However problems seems to come when out is of type unsigned int * or float *. it's puzzling why data type matters.

Comment: Just post your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: seems like problem in test environment. sorry for inconvenience. This is not reproducible now.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCL 1.x, the global work size must be an integer multiple of the local size. Yours is not (1920 / 512 = not an integer).